# can you explain for me more detail this tutorial, please?

Tags: ip, pfsense

I see this tutorial, http://djinnsour.com/2015/08/23/adding-a-public-ip-address-to-a-system-behind-pfsense-using-nat-11/. Author of this blog say, add external ip to this network, so what is the public ip ( whatismyip ) of that machine?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to that tutorial, the external IP address (routable) would be the 222.222.222.x range address.

Anything within 192.168.x.x will be a private range which can only be used internally as per RFC1918 hence why you would use NAT.

Hope this helps you on your quest.

SleepyMan

Comment: yes, thank you but that not i want. Is mean they type 222.222.222.10 and become public ip, not liked public ip have been available like we know.? what is that about?

Comment: That is a valid public IP but obviously it is only an example. This particular IP range is belongs to China and has been assigned to China Telecom hebei.

Comment: Yes they should have use an IP from [rfc5737](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5737)  but not everybody is aware of this, it's common to pick any IP as example rather than the official documentation IPs.